# Android: pause and restart a thread, using flags vs .wait() and .notify()

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm programming an application that has to start, pause and restart a thread deppending on the buttons the user press [Start and Abort]. To control the thread I create a Service to work with the Activity, like follows:

Code of the Activity

```
public class SoundLocalizer extends Activity {

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, " ON CREATE ");

        // Set up the window layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

     public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

        mHelloService = new HelloMessage(ThisContext, mHandler, LocalIP);
        mHelloService.start();

        setup();
    }


    public void onReStart(){

        mHelloService.restart();
    }

    public void onWait(){

        mHelloService.stop();

        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON WAIT --");
    }

    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");


        mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                //The aplicacion have already been lauched
                if(Begin){

                    onReStart();
                }
                isRecording = true;
                enableButtons(false);



            }
        });

        mAbortButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbort);
        mAbortButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                enableButtons(true);

                Loop=false;
                isRecording=false;
                WaitForMaster=false;
                onWait();   
                Begin=true;


            }
        });

}



}
```

Code of the Service

```
public class HelloMessage {

    Context mContext ;
    private final Handler mHandler;     
    private boolean Working=true;


    public HelloMessage(Context context, Handler handler, String IP){

        mContext=context;
        mHandler = handler;
        Local_IP_String=IP;
        String[] IP_Parts = IP.split("\\.");
        LocalIP=Integer.parseInt(IP_Parts[3]);

     }

     public void restart() {        

     Working=true;               

    /*
    mHelloThread.notify();
    */

 }


 public synchronized void start() {

    Working=true;                
    mHelloThread = new HelloThread();
     mHelloThread.start();

     }


public void stop() {

    Working=false;

            /*
    try {
        mHelloThread.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     */

    }

public class HelloThread extends Thread {

     DatagramSocket mSocket ;
     InetAddress myBcastIP;  

        public HelloThread() {

            try { 

                       //Here I initialize some variables

             } catch (IOException e) { 

                 ...
             }

        }

        public void run(){

            //Listen on socket to receive messages 
            try{                

                        while(Working){                 

                                  //Do things

                            }

                        }


             } catch (IOException e) { 

                      ...

             }


}
```

Problems: When I press Abort, the activity calls:  *mHelloService.stop()*  correctly, and the flag *Working* becomes **false**, and the "While loop" in the thread of the service stop working.

Until this point, everything perfect. But then I want to restart the loop calling the method *mHelloService.restart()* that should make *Working* become **true**, but the thread doesn't start again. What am I doing wrong?

------------ Other version I also tried with even worse result ---------------

Using mHelloThread.wait() in *mHelloService.stop()* and  mHelloThread.notify() in *mHelloService.restart()*

I got this in the LogCat:

> 09-02 02:08:54.640: D/AndroidRuntime(17463): Shutting down VM 09-02
>   02:08:54.640: W/dalvikvm(17463): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x413eb300) 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException:
>   object not locked by thread before wait() 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   09-02 02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364) 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   android.nacho.SoundLocalizer.HelloMessage.stop(HelloMessage.java:88)
>   09-02 02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   android.nacho.SoundLocalizer.SoundLocalizer.onWait(SoundLocalizer.java:367)
>   09-02 02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   android.nacho.SoundLocalizer.SoundLocalizer$3.onClick(SoundLocalizer.java:441)
>   09-02 02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 09-02
>   02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 09-02
>   02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-02
>   02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 09-02
>   02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-02
>   02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-02 02:08:54.648:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   09-02 02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 09-02
>   02:08:54.648: E/AndroidRuntime(17463):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thank you very much for your time

---

Note 1:

If I add mHelloThread.start() in restart() I get this in the LogCat:

> 09-02 03:05:07.664: D/AndroidRuntime(17657): Shutting down VM 09-02
>   03:05:07.664: W/dalvikvm(17657): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x413eb300) 09-02 03:05:07.672:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17657): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-02 03:05:07.672:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17657): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread
>   already started. 09-02 03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):     at
>   java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045) 09-02 03:05:07.672:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   android.nacho.SoundLocalizer.HelloMessage.restart(HelloMessage.java:67)
>   09-02 03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   android.nacho.SoundLocalizer.SoundLocalizer.onReStart(SoundLocalizer.java:353)
>   09-02 03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   android.nacho.SoundLocalizer.SoundLocalizer$2.onClick(SoundLocalizer.java:421)
>   09-02 03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 09-02 03:05:07.672:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 09-02
>   03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 09-02
>   03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-02
>   03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 09-02 03:05:07.672:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 09-02
>   03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-02
>   03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 09-02 03:05:07.672:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   09-02 03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 09-02
>   03:05:07.672: E/AndroidRuntime(17657):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: The exception you are getting is the  java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait() . You need to perform synchronizing of the object within your code

Comment: I'm quite new with Android and I'm not sure about how to perform the synchronizing of the object, but I will investigate a little bit. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Slightly offtopic: why do you wish to do everything by hand? What is the sense of your "Service" class? If you wish to implement an Android `Service`, you must extend `Service` and add it to the manifest.

---

To your specific question:
Your `restart` method does not restart the Thread, it only changes a variable. You'd need to call `start` again, as it completely stopped (the `run` method is completely executed, the variable is no longer checked). You could use other synchronization methods if you need to ensure only one instance is running.

As a single `Thread` can only get executed once, you need to ether create a new thread object, or implement an own start-behaviour (letting the Thread wait until it gets interrupted, or similar).

Btw, your variable `Working` is not thread-safe. Mark it as `volatile` to work around possible synchronization issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. About the offtopic, I use a service because the Thread has to manage a UDP sockect, and I found an example where they combine a Service with a thread with a handler in the Activity to work with the received messages. About the main question. That means I should include mHelloThread.start(); into the onRestart() as well??

Comment: Ok I tried it, but in the logCat I get what I pasted below Note 1. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: @nacho22 `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.` Seems like you called restart while the thread was still executing. I agree that my answer is not that explicit on that case, I'll rephrase the bit: You need to use other synchronization methods to ensure that your thread goes down completely before starting it again. Multiple possibilities for that, you could use a `Mutex` or the built-in `synchronized` keyword with a shared object, choose the one you like the most.

Comment: But with the synchronization what do I get? I was thinking in just kill the thread, and restart it. Could it be done with the combination .interrupt() and .join()?

Comment: Killing a thread is [not safe and thus deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), don't do that. You can either create a new thread, or synchronize the one you have currently. You could also use other threading mechanisms such as thread pools, if you don't want to do that manually.